Serialport error in vue-electron on Windows 10
First , I create a project
vue create demo
cd demo
vue add electron-builder

It's ok here,
then the error
yarn add serialport
yarn add v1.22.19
....
└─ serialport@12.0.0
$ electron-builder install-app-deps
  • electron-builder  version=22.14.13
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=@serialport/bindings-cpp@12.0.1 platform=win32 arch=x64
  • rebuilding native dependency  name=@serialport/bindings-cpp version=12.0.1
  ⨯ cannot execute  cause=fork/exec C:\Users\kerwin\.yarn\releases\yarn-1.22.19.cjs: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
                    command='C:\Users\kerwin\.yarn\releases\yarn-1.22.19.cjs' run install
                    workingDir=C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\@serialport\bindings-cpp
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

then I install @electron/rebuild
C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper>yarn add --dev @electron/rebuild
yarn add v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
...
$ electron-builder install-app-deps
  • electron-builder  version=22.14.13
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=@serialport/bindings-cpp@12.0.1 platform=win32 arch=x64
  • rebuilding native dependency  name=@serialport/bindings-cpp version=12.0.1
  ⨯ cannot execute  cause=fork/exec C:\Users\kerwin\.yarn\releases\yarn-1.22.19.cjs: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
                    command='C:\Users\kerwin\.yarn\releases\yarn-1.22.19.cjs' run install
                    workingDir=C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\@serialport\bindings-cpp
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

then I run electron-builder.cmd
C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper>.\node_modules\.bin\electron-builder.cmd
  • electron-builder  version=22.14.13 os=10.0.19045
  • description is missed in the package.json  appPackageFile=C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\package.json
  • author is missed in the package.json  appPackageFile=C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\package.json
  • writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=@serialport/bindings-cpp@12.0.1 platform=win32 arch=x64
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=13.6.9 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  ⨯ Application entry file "background.js" in the "C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar" does not exist. Seems like a wrong configuration.  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: Application entry file "background.js" in the "C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar" does not exist. Seems like a wrong configuration.
    at error (C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\asar\asarFileChecker.ts:7:12)
    at Object.checkFileInArchive (C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\asar\asarFileChecker.ts:31:11)
    at WinPackager.checkFileInPackage (C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\platformPackager.ts:501:7)
    at WinPackager.sanityCheckPackage (C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\platformPackager.ts:549:5)
    at WinPackager.doPack (C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\platformPackager.ts:310:5)
    at WinPackager.pack (C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\platformPackager.ts:136:5)
    at Packager.doBuild (C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:441:9)
    at Object.executeFinally (C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\builder-util\src\promise.ts:12:14)
    at Packager._build (C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:376:31)
    at Packager.build (C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:337:12)
    at Object.executeFinally (C:\Users\kerwin\Desktop\com_helper\node_modules\builder-util\src\promise.ts:12:14)


win10
node :v20.16.0
@vue/cli 5.0.8
electron  v31.4.0

I find background.js in src, why?
